# integral k-algebra and geometrically integral k-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to show the following statement.

**Assume $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Let $R$ be a $k$-algebra $R$. Then, $R$ is an integral $k$-algebra if and only if $R$ is a geometrically integral $k$-algebra.**

**Definition**: We say that a ring $R$ is an *integral $k$-algebra* if it is a $k$-algebra that is an integral domain. We say that a ring $R$ is an *geometrically integral $k$-algebra* if it is a $k$-algebra such that for every field extension $k'\supset k$, the ring $R\otimes_{k}k'$ is an integral $k'$-algebra.

"if"-part is trivial but I don't know how to prove "only if"-part. In fact, this is an exercise problem in the algebra class (not algebraic geometry) so I just know the basic definition of tensor product.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find this page helpful: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00I2

Comment: Really? In fact, I also saw "stacks.math.columbia..." before posting but did not find a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thanks.